# How do I call NSManagedObject validateValue from textFieldDidEndEditing in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I want to update the model and perform validation everytime textfield changes. 
I am currently in thetextFieldDidEndEditing delegate but I am having hard time figuring out what to pass in the validateValue method

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {

 updateCustomObject() // sets the property to the value of the textfield

 // What is the proper syntax here
 customObject.validateValue(AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>, forKeyPath: <String>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your custom object, override validateForInsert and/or validateForUpdate:

Once this is done, simply save your managed objects and catch the errors:

(This is just an example and not working code...)

```
do {
   try managedObjectContext.save()
catch {
  if let validationError = error as? ValidationError {
      //inform the user or do something useful here
  }
}
```

Your custom Object could contain the following (example, not complete or working)

```
enum ValidationError: ErrorType {
    case TooLong
    case TooShort
}

extension CustomObject {

    override func validateForInsert() throws {
        //similar to below
    }

    override func validateForUpdate() throws {
        let success = //some conditions
        if success == false {
            throw ValidationError.TooLong
        }
    }
...
```

Comment: Thank you. I have this already implemented but I want to validate individual property as it gets updated so I need to call the custom methods one by one.

Comment: why not validate those properties as in validateForUpdate? you can have a validation error for each of your properties and check them one after the other.

Comment: validateForInsert/Update will trigger additional rules that are combination of multiple properties evaluation. The goal is to validate individual property/input as the user completes it.

Comment: I think it is as simple as doing this but I skipped ObjectiveC and pointers are not my strong side

       do {
                var val: AnyObject? = customObject.state
                try customObject.validateValue(&val, forKeyPath: "state")
            } catch let error as NSError {
                
                // show error here
                
            }

Comment: You have to make sure you call super for validateForInsert or validateForUpdate.